# Mysql Join Using Timedifference on Timestamps

Tags: mysql, join, unique, closest

I have two tables, killlog and deathlog recording death and kill information from an online game. I would like to join these two tables in order to produce a kill board.

This is possible by looking at the timestamps kills and deaths are logged and joining the closest death in terms of time to each kill. The time differences between kill and death are relatively close usually but can range by as much as 10 minutes.

I want to match EACH kill with the CLOSEST death in terms of timedifference, however I only want to match each death to a single kill.

Currently I have the following SQL statement

```
SELECT
distinct killlog.ID, deathlog.id, killlog.PlayerName, deathlog.PlayerName, killlog.Timestamp as killtime, deathlog.Timestamp as deathtime, 
TIMEDIFF(killlog.Timestamp, deathlog.Timestamp)
FROM killlog
inner JOIN deathlog on
TIMEDIFF(killlog.Timestamp, deathlog.Timestamp) <= 600 
GROUP by 
killlog.id
```

This is almost giving me the desired output, however in some instances I am seeing deaths matched to multiple kills. Eg:

```
+--------+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| killID | DeathID | KillerName | VictimName | killTime            | deathTime           | timeDiff |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|      8 |      28 | DKmintz    | Hanfkeks   | 09/12/2013 21:30:23 | 09/12/2013 21:30:09 | 00:00:14 |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|      9 |      28 | Sam Fisher | Hanfkeks   | 09/12/2013 21:31:03 | 09/12/2013 21:30:09 | 00:00:54 |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Here you can see the same death being matched to two different kills.

My question is how do I ensure I am only returning each death once and am not joining the same death to multiple kills.

Answer (score 0):

```
TIMEDIFF(killlog.Timestamp, deathlog.Timestamp) <= 600 
GROUP by

Here insted of groub by use partiotion by(kill time)<=600 and you will 
8   28  DKmintz Hanfkeks    09/12/2013 21:30:23 09/12/2013 21:30:09 00:00:14 record
```

Comment: `SELECT
    distinct killlog.ID, deathlog.id, killlog.PlayerName, deathlog.PlayerName, killlog.Timestamp as killtime, deathlog.Timestamp as deathtime, 
    TIMEDIFF(killlog.Timestamp, deathlog.Timestamp)
    FROM killlog
    inner JOIN deathlog on
    TIMEDIFF(killlog.Timestamp, deathlog.Timestamp) <= 600 

partition by 
TIMEDIFF(killlog.Timestamp, deathlog.Timestamp) <= 600`


This results in SQL errors, I cannot find much information on "partition by" for MySQL to see where the problem is though.